# How to open numbers spreadsheet in 2 separate windows

Tags: numbers

I often find it useful to have two tabs of one spreadsheet open in separate windows. In Excel this is easy (Windows/New Window).

Is there any way to achieve this in Numbers (as of Version 3.5)?

For the record, I've tried searching for an answer to this, but needless to say, searches including "Numbers" and "Windows" doesn't lead to anything useful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thinking about this some more, I have figured out a workaround. Though it's not altogether satisfactory, it could be useful in some cases. The workaround is iCloud.

Save the Numbers spreadsheet to iCloud drive, and then open it from a web browser. Open a new browser window and again open the spreadsheet from iCloud drive and you now have the spreadsheet open in 2 windows.

You could also have a local copy open in Numbers, with additional windows provided by iCloud browser windows, though there would be some lag between local changes appearing in iCloud and visa versa.

Comment: That's a very clever workaround!

Answer (score 2):

There is a (clumsy) workaround. From the File menu select Duplicate and a new window will open with a copy of the spreadsheet. Just be care to use it only to read and make updates to the original spreadsheet. When you are done, you can close and choose delete on the copy.

Answer (score 1):

This is currently not possible. You can provide feedback to Apple here:

- https://www.apple.com/feedback/numbers.html

Comment: Thanks for the definitive answer - I've sent the feedback to Apple too.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround - you can open a spreadsheet, then press <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>, choose the first template, and open the spreadsheet from that new window.

[image]

Comment: Sorry, but that makes no sense to me... if I do cmd-N and choose the first template, I just get a new, blank spreadsheet. You're screenshot looks like an older version of Numbers - maybe what you suggest no longer works in the current version?

Comment: @rowatt possibly! Sorry I didn't pay attention to the version. Basically what I did to achieve the above was: 1. Open a spreadsheet 2. Press Cmd+N 3. Create new spreadsheet by clicking the template 4. 2 windows are now open. It may be that this doesn't work in the latest version - but your workaround is very clever - +1!

Comment: I can open 2 windows in Numbers, but not two windows from the same document. Is your method allowing 2 windows for one document in the older version?

Comment: @rowatt yes - older version, sorry about that!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Numbers does not support two windows like Excel but there are alternatives.

Firstly open the Numbers file in Numbers and the second file in Preview. Resize the windows and each can be seen alongside each other and compared. Only the numbers file can be edited but the comparison of two spreadsheets and the cross referencing of information is good. The thing to do is to open the file which you want to alter or change in Numbers.

You can also do this with one window using Numbers and the other OpenOffice which is a free download. When you then have two windows open you can swap between programmes and not only compare files but alter both if needed . I find this a good way to compare say membership lists and reconcile payments against Bank statements.

Transfer of files from numbers to OpenOffice is easy as Numbers will export to a different format including CSV and this can then be taken up in Office.